# C++ Xerces-c - How to tell if node is placeholder

Tags: c++, xml-parsing, xerces-c

I've been working on an XML Parser using C++ and Xerces-c, but I seem to have hit a problem that I can't figure out (not a major problem, I can get a work around but don't wanna "hack" my way around it :))

I have a XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Config>
<Person>
    <Title>Mr.</Title>
    <Forename>Stephen</Forename>
    <Surname>Cassidy</Surname>
    <Job>
        <Title>Position1</Title>
        <Position>Worker</Position>
        <Salary>£6.40</Salary>
    </Job>
    <Job>
        <Title>NewJob</Title>
        <Position>PositionWorker1</Position>
        <Position>AnotherPosition</Position>
        <Salary>£12,000</Salary>
    </Job>
</Person>
```

What I'm trying to do is figure out if a node is just a "placeholder" for other child nodes e.g. like the `<Person>` node or the `<Job>` node, and just check it for child nodes, rather than attempt any processing.

The reason for this is i am storing the nodes values within a class that stores the node name (e.g. Title) and value (e.g. NewJob), as well as a list of child entries, so Job would be a node entry, then Title, Position and Salary will all be "child" entries of Job. However I want to be able to check too see if Job has an entry for Position already, and rather than make a new entry and add it too Job, just add the value of Position to the already existing Position entry... if that makes sense to anyone :)

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm not expecting anyone to code it or anything for me just a few hints or pointers :)!

Comment: Why do you store your Nodes in your own classes? Xerces offers structures for that. In general I'd think about checking the name of each child entry and returning the node if it's 'Position'.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use the SAX parser in this case. If you build your own objects you don't need to create the DOM and you can easily fill your own objects during the SAX run. This will reduce memory consumption and is likely much faster on processing large files.

Basically, using the SAX parser is a sequence of

```
SAX2XMLReaderImpl*  sax_parser = new SAX2XMLReaderImpl();
MyDefaultHandler*  docHandler = new MyDefaultHandler(); // derived from DefaultHandler

sax_parser->setContentHandler(docHandler);
sax_parser->parse(pszPath);
```

A detailed documentation of the SAX interface can be found here:
[SAX2XMLReader](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classSAX2XMLReader.html#a1885becac34443e9648ccaeeed733f5)

You will be called through the callbacks implemented in your MyDefaultHandler class while Xerces is parsing the XML. Fill your objects there based on your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This can be done using DOM parsers. Parsers typically flag the different types of nodes (case in point being text-nodes/plain-char-data-nodes) encountered.

Comment: Sure they (DOM parsers) are doing this. But why should one create a DOM tree if an own data structure is also created. Without more information I takes this fact from the original question as given and therefore it is better to not create a DOM tree also.

Comment: My reading of OP's question was the other way round: I was of the opinion that (s)he is using a DOM parser.

Comment: Yeah I am using a DOM Parser, I couldn't really get my head around SAX lol plus the files are pretty small (no more than a few mb) anyways so memory isn't an issue thankfully :)

Comment: A few MB is not really a lot in the moment. Hopefully the size of the files won't get bigger over the time.

Comment: I actually got it working eventually... problem was all down to a badly placed if statement believe it or not! Might try SAX out at some point - surely it would be ok to do this
DOMDocument* new = parser->getDocument ();
// code to parse and store nodes //
delete new;

since the document is no longer needed as all values are stored elsewhere?

Comment: @SCassidy1986 The DOM document is owned by the parser. So if you delete the parser object the document is also released. However, you can call resetDocumentPool() to release any document(s) before deleting the parser.

Answer (score 0):

`Job` should have type `ELEMENT_NODE` whereas the other should have type `TEXT_NODE`. You can use the [`getNodeType()`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-3/classDOMNode.html#4ceca7c2d979f1e42c4d96329fbd7bc1) member to check for the type and then proceed as required.

Comment: Hmmm I had tried that but for some reason <Job> was coming up as an ELEMENT_NODE, then the whitespace after it was showing up as a TEXT_NODE, so in my code it was being processed as a node that contains a value :S It's not a big problem this, as I've come up with a work around but would be nice to figure it out properly rather than use a hack :P

Comment: @SCassidy1986: This is because the parser is preserving whitespace handling. It is likely that this behavior can be turned off. Can you try out `DocumentHandler::ignorableWhitespace()`?

Comment: I still believe using the SAX parser this task would be easier ;-)

Comment: @xml-tools.com: SAX has its advantages surely, but it can be just that tad bit unwieldy at times.